# acf field data in do_shortcode not populating

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the WordPress Advanced Custom Field plugin. I have a custom built download button and shortcode. Now I am using ACF fields to populate the download btn shortcode. Everything seems to be working and download button is displaying as expected. The  only problem is that ACF fields are not populating in the shortcode but its showing outside the shortcode code.

```
<?php

  if (get_field('dn_btn_url1')) { 

    echo do_shortcode( '[download_btn url="'.get_field('dn_btn_url1').'" filename="'.get_field('dn_btn_txt1').'"]' );

  }

?>
```

The code without the if statement is working as expected but it doesn't hide the shortcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`get_field`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) function gets the post id from the global `$post` object so when it's passed into the shortcode function, it seems like it can't get the right post id. Try putting your URL from the field into a variable so the URL is already passed through the function and into the shortcode function.

Try this:

```php
<?php

  if (get_field('dn_btn_url1')) {

    $url = get_field('dn_btn_url1');

    echo do_shortcode( '[download_btn url="' . $url . '" filename="' . $url . '"]' );

  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using sprintf function please try it once

```php
<?php 
  if(get_fiedl('dn_btn_url1')) {
  $url = get_field('dn_btn_url1');
  $filename = get_field('dn_btn_txt1');
  $shortcode = sprintf(
  '[download_btn url="'.$url.'" , 
  filename="'.$filename.'"]');
  echo do_shortcode( $shortcode );
?>
```